# Regex Search and Replace in Eclipse: How do I fix dangling meta character 'x'?

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

I am trying to replace function calls written when methods were nonstatic to an updated version were they are.
For example: TABLE_foo(table1, ...rest is the same
with
table1.foo(...rest is the same

This is what I have come up with using my limited understanding of regex and this site.
find:

```
TABLE_(*)\((*),
```

replace:

```
$2.$1(
```

The above yields a dangling meta character '*' error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The main part of it is working fine now, but I can't get it to terminate properly. I don't know if the second thing you mentioned is what I need to do or not but I am ending up with:
table1, 1, 1.foo( "string");
when it should look like:
table1.foo(1, 1, "string");

find: TABLE_(.*)\((.*),(.*)\)
replace: $2.$1\($3\)

I don't necessarily think I should need to collect the third item either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Eclipse uses Java-style regexes, try using `TABLE_(.*)\((.*)` as your find expression.

`*` means "zero or more of the previous character", and you did not have a previous character so it didn't know what to look for. I inserted a `.` before them to indicate "any character", but it may work better with `[^)]*` if it uses greedy matching.